# Netbeans on new build or run, terminate previous ones

Tags: netbeans

I would like to terminate all things I've done when i execute a task - build, run. With that i mean tasks - process, which are shown below in tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need to close the tabs by pressing the 'x' in the top right of the output window. This is found in the menu bar at the top 'Window-->Output'. The tab for output will contain the word 'run:' and will have a title similar to Output - Example(run)#1.
Then at the bottom of Netbeans on the status bar there should be a progress bar with an 'x' at the end indicating any running projects. You need to close this also.

Or you can go to the menu bar at the top and select 'Run-->Stop Build/Run'

Comment: Can you force NetBeans to automatically stop previous run?

Comment: It will stop if Netbeans reaches the end of your code or if there is a statement to tell it to terminate, for example in Java you would write `System.exit(0);`.